# Popular meta questions sidebar MIA

Tags: support

Until recently there has been three categories in the yellow box at the top of the SO sidebar, "Blog", "Featured on Meta", and "Popular Meta Questions" (or some such, I forget the exact wording).

I rather liked the third category, as it often had interesting meta questions in it, but it has not been there for a few days now. Was it removed? Why? Can I get it back?

Comment: This question is now in the "Hot Meta Posts" category in the sidebar :)

Comment: @AlexK whoah now *that* is meta

Answer (score 9):

There are a maximum of 4 slots on the yellow box. These get filled by blog posts, featured posts on meta, and popular meta posts if there are slots left. More information on this can be found on [this global meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/158100).

Since two slots are filled by the blog, and two slots are filled by featured meta posts, that leaves 0 slots for popular meta posts.

As soon as a slot will become available, you will see popular meta questions again.

Comment: 6 slots wouldn't be too much, I also kinda miss this category.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 two errors: 1. You are assuming all users here are hetero or not with migration background. 2. You are assuming the post you are refering, has taken more than 6-8 weeks. You should unit test your assumptions :P

Comment: I've just read the duplicate, the answer is an explanation of the behavior. But... why such complexity, leading to people not seeing what they want ? I'm not pushing anyone, but I'd like to know it's eventually going to be solved.